# XAMPP MySQL won't start on Mac Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I have install XAMPP a long time ago and now MySQL won't start.

I already have this problem and I think I just added this line to XAMPP file in `xamppfiles` folder to start MySQL.

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I try to start MySQL on the teminal, with:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

I get an error:

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MBP-de-IMYMY.pid`).

Yesterday, it stopped working when I opened the XAMPP manager. I did nothing and it stopped working.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in and add any other methods that you tried to solve the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Solution:

Looking for some running mysql-processes:

```
sudo ps aux | grep mysql
```

It returns something like this:

```
root            13425   1,2  0,0  2432772   ...
_mysql           7545   0,0  0,1  2606424   ...
root              315   0,0  0,0  2434396   ...
root            13420   0,0  0,0  2434392   ...
```

Then kill them all by typing:

```
sudo kill -9 7545
```

Restart the MySql-Services again...